# How can I send calendar information from webservice to iphone app?

Tags: iphone, web-services, calendar

I want to create  or use an open source php calendar as a webservice. This is just one feature of an entire app idea of mine, but I'm working on the app in steps and would like to start with a calendar. Is there a way to use a php calendar to update an iphone apps calendar? Example, I want to be able to add an appointment within the iphone app and have it update on the php calendar on my website? I want syncronization both ways. If I decide to add an event on the calendar through the website, I would like it to update in the iphone app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the maximum amount of customization I would go the route of writing your own calendar in PHP. Then you can make the calendar work exactly how you want and it can work seamlessly with your App. This shouldnt be too difficult as for a class project I had to right a simple PHP Calendar (it didnt have web services but still). Ray Wenderlich discusses several ways of using web services in iOS apps, and even has an example based on PHP/MySQL.

- [How To Write A Simple PHP/MySQL Web Service for an iOS App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app)
- [How
  To Write An iOS App That Uses A Web Service](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service)